# Support Beam Hole

Tags: construction

How do I repair a 10" support beam with a 6" hole cut through it short of replacing the support beam? We have not tried anything yet.  What would you recommend?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to tell; could you add more info (e.g. what's the beam made of, a picture)? Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact width, height and span? Is the hole located in the middle 1/3 of the span? Exactly how far from the support is the hole located? What is the load on it?

Comment: @LeeSam even if the hole is centred on the centreline of the beam, it will exceed the « middle third » so it’s not like a 1" hole...

Comment: @SolarMike True. It needs to be repaired...but how will depend on the original size, location of hole, load, etc.